# Wait for window to close before running ajax.done

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, window

I don't really know if this is possible without refreshing the page, but basically I have a form that a user can fill in, then in the event that they are not logged in a popup is triggered. If the user selects that they want to login with Facebook I want to authorise the login server side. I do this by opening a new window at the location of the authorisation.

I want to handle the data from the new window then close it after it has loaded and authorised the user.

At the moment I have:

```
sessionSetRequest.done(function(){

     var facebookAuthWindow = window.open(window.location.origin + '/auth/facebook');
     facebookAuthWindow.onload = function(){
         facebookAuthWindow.close();
     };
});
```

But the `.onload()` function is not called.

Alternatively, is there a way for me to close the new window by loading a page that closes itself, then running another function within the original page?

Many many pre-emptive thanks for your help; and on the topic of help, you might want to check out the site I'm building (;

www.dev.thinkshare.it/about

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Comment: Done that down below! It's really strange, it works when I test it on the W3Schools editor, but when I try to do it the `.onload()` method doesn't appear to be called. Could this be because it is inside a `request.done()` function?

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail would help. In the site that you provided, I went to the "Share" link, entered some stuff and before submitting a popup came up with options to either login or register. I tried to register and when I clicked "Register", only them the form posted and my "idea" (which is nothing but a random string) got posted. I was using chrome.

Are you talking about the same usecase? Do you want that when you click on "Register" or "Login", form should not post back?

Comment: No it's to do with the Facebook login, I try to log the user in using another window, then close the window and go back to the form. This way I don't lose what they've typed and I don't have to store anything until the user is actually logged in.

Comment: I have this at the moment:

`var facebookAuthWindow = window.open(window.location.origin + "/auth/facebook");
        
        facebookAuthWindow.onload = function(){
            facebookAuthWindow.close();
        };`

Comment: "a popup is triggered via AJAX."- this comment earlier and your latest comments have me confused. The above code does not seem to be AJAX. Can you please edit your original post and give a detailed description of the problem with relevant code samples.

Comment: I can see what you have now. What is it that you require is still not clear. Do you want that the form should not submit till `facebookAuthWindow.close();` is called?

Comment: Well that's the thing, the close operation is not executing. I need the window to load first because only then will the user be authenticated.